# How to define recurrence events model in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, calendar

I am trying to make a Calendar app. I want to persist the events into Core Data. But the situation is like this, if I want to a recurring event like "every day at 6 AM wake me up". How to define this event model in Core Data? And should I calculate the events from now on to like next year, and save all these events back into Core Data, or I just save one event to Core Data but have a recurrence rule set it to like "every day at 6 AM". Is there any tutorial online like this I can learn about?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how big the application is (how many features does it have).

- If it doesn't have much features, then your second idea is the way to go - Just have a flag in your core-data entity of "Recurring" to set it's a recurring event. Load all events from your core-data model and then filter the
  recurring events from the normal ones. Now, set up local/remote
  notifications based on your logic.
- Otherwise, You can create it more abstract with an abstract entity "Event" and some entities that inherit from it like: "Normal Event", "Recurring Event" - Each fulfilling its own logic. That way, when you load the entities from your core-data model, you just fetch every "Event" entity (which will be both normal and recurring) and apply any logic you need.

You can explore some of the projects [here](http://code4app.net/category/calendar) to see some calendar application references.